# Получить список активных пользователей windows С#

Tags: c#

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount WHERE Disabled=false");
foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(envVar["Name"] + Environment.NewLine);
    listBox2.Items.Add(envVar["Name"] + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Но выводит он мне помимо активных пользователей ещё и аккаунт  `ASPNET`. Как мне сделать, чтобы выводил только активных пользователей без учёток `ASPNET` и других программ?

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в запрос условие `SIDType = 1`, которое выберет именно пользователей:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount WHERE Disabled=false AND SIDType = 1");
foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(envVar["Name"] + Environment.NewLine);
    listBox2.Items.Add(envVar["Name"] + Environment.NewLine);
}
```